# Gram Matrix for Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Let $U = P_1(\mathbb{R})$. Consider the bilinear form (−,−) on $U$ given by
$(u, v) =$ $\int_{0}^{1} u(x)v(x) dx$
for all $u, v ∈ U$. You may use without proof the fact that (−,−) is an inner product.

(a) Find the Gram matrix of (−,−) with respect to the basis {$1,t$} of $U$.

I have

\begin{bmatrix} 1&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}

I don't think this is correct as if the bilinear form is an inner product, then its gram matrix should be symmetric, but mine isn't. Can I have some help?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 1&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$  is correct. It *is* a symmetric matrix.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry I was being a complete and utter idiot. Thanks for the help.